# Losing contents of .hg folder with TortoiseHg

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg, bitbucket

So I have been working fine, committing, pushing to BitBucket. I went in to add  a couple of extensions, restarted THG and now my repo shows as if it was brand new like I never did anything. I looked at the .hg folder and there was nothing in there!

So I cloned the repo from BitBucket under another name, moved the contents of the .hg folder to the old repo and changed the name in hgrc folder. Come to start using it today and was getting an error in the status bar. I restarted  THG and it was back to like I have done nothing.

Why is this happening? Really frustrating. I am new to Mercurial, but I don't believe I did anything to warrant this?

Comment: Could you post some more information about version of TortoiseHg you are using and the error you saw in the status bar? Some more information about the extensions might also help. What you are seeing is not usual, but I can't make any guesses about the cause based on your question.

Comment: I don't recall what the error was exactly, something like ERR3 I think. The plugins I activated were, fetch, progress and extdiff. Here is the version info

version 2.4.2
with Mercurial-2.2.3, Python-2.7.3, PyQt-4.9.1, Qt-4.8.0

Comment: Are you using any shared network drives or is everything on your local workstation? Also, running `hg verify` is a good way of finding out if your repository is sound or corrupt.

Comment: no network drives. It just happened again.   
IOError: [Errno 13] C:\TestSite\.hg/store\00changelog.i: Access is denied  
all i have now in .hg is dir store which I can't open and thgstatus which is 0k.  this is getting bad. I just updated to THG 2.5 also.

Comment: are your files read-only? This may be why you're seeing this error. An `attrib -r * /s` should fix that. It would also be worthwhile to review the security settings on the folders and files.